# Drop items from a hierarchy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tree

I have some tree structure like this

[image]

Some nodes in the tree will be disabled. The child nodes of disabled nodes need to get connected to the parent node of the disabled node. If that one is disabled to then to the following parent and so on.

In this picture node 2 is disabled and node 4 and 5 get connected to the parent of node 2, which is node 1

[image]

This would be the result

[image]

A more complex case id where the parent of a disabled node is also disabled

[image][image]

In this sample, I get all child nodes of some testdata but I have no idea if it is possible to drop the disabled nodes but keep the child nodes connected to the next possible parent

```
CREATE TABLE #Node
(
     Id INT, 
     ParentID INT, 
     Name NVARCHAR(20),   
     skipNode BIT
);

INSERT INTO #Node 
VALUES (1, NULL, 'node-1', 0),
       (2, 1, 'node-2', 1),
       (3, 1, 'node-3', 0),
       (4, 2, 'node-4', 0),
       (5, 2, 'node-5', 0),
       (6, 3, 'node-6', 0),
       (7, 4, 'node-6', 0),
       (8, 4, 'node-6', 0);

WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        anchor.Id AS ItemId, 
        skipNode,
        anchor.ParentId AS ItemParentId, 
        1 AS Lvl, 
        anchor.[Name],
        CAST(name AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS NodePath
    FROM
        #Node anchor 
    WHERE 
        anchor.[Id] = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        nextDepth.Id AS ItemId, 
        nextDepth.skipNode, 
        nextDepth.ParentId AS ItemParentId, 
        Lvl+1 AS Lvl, 
        nextDepth.[Name],
        CAST((rec.NodePath + '/' + nextDepth.[Name]) AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS NodePath
    FROM 
        #Node nextDepth
    INNER JOIN 
        RCTE rec ON nextDepth.ParentId = rec.ItemId
)
SELECT ItemId, skipNode , ItemParentId, [Name], NodePath
FROM RCTE AS hierarchy

DROP TABLE #Node
```

The expected result with a disabled node 2 would be

```
ItemId      skipNode ItemParentId Name   
----------- -------- ------------ -------
1           0        NULL         node-1 
3           0        1            node-3 
6           0        3            node-6 
4           0        1            node-4 
5           0        1            node-5 
7           0        4            node-6 
8           0        4            node-6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example should get you going:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.GetParentNode;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetParentNode
( 
    @NodePath varchar(max)
)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
    /*
        SELECT dbo.GetParentNode('12/13/14');
        SELECT dbo.GetParentNode('12/14');
    */

    DECLARE @ReturnValue int;
    DECLARE @StringToProcess varchar(max) = REVERSE(@NodePath);
    DECLARE @DelimiterLocation int;

    SET @DelimiterLocation = CHARINDEX('/', @StringToProcess);

    IF @DelimiterLocation > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @StringToProcess = SUBSTRING(@StringToProcess, @DelimiterLocation + 1, LEN(@StringToProcess));
        SET @DelimiterLocation = CHARINDEX('/', @StringToProcess);

        IF @DelimiterLocation = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = CAST(REVERSE(@StringToProcess) AS int);
        END ELSE BEGIN
            SET @ReturnValue = CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(@StringToProcess, @DelimiterLocation - 1)) AS int);
        END;
    END;

    RETURN @ReturnValue;   
END;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Nodes;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Nodes
(
     NodeID int, 
     ParentNodeID int, 
     NodeName nvarchar(20),   
     IsDisabled bit
);

INSERT dbo.Nodes 
(
    NodeID, ParentNodeID, NodeName, IsDisabled
)
VALUES (1, NULL, 'node-1', 0),
       (2, 1, 'node-2', 1),
       (3, 1, 'node-3', 0),
       (4, 2, 'node-4', 0),
       (5, 2, 'node-5', 0),
       (6, 3, 'node-6', 0),
       (7, 4, 'node-6', 0),
       (8, 4, 'node-6', 0);

WITH AllNodes AS
(
    SELECT toplevel.NodeID, 
           toplevel.IsDisabled,
           toplevel.ParentNodeID, 
           1 AS NodeLevel, 
           toplevel.NodeName, 
           CAST(toplevel.NodeID AS varchar(max)) AS NodePath
    FROM dbo.Nodes AS toplevel 
    WHERE toplevel.NodeID = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        n.NodeID, 
        n.IsDisabled, 
        n.ParentNodeID, 
        an.NodeLevel + 1, 
        n.NodeName,
        an.NodePath + CASE WHEN n.IsDisabled = 0 
                           THEN '/' + CAST(n.NodeID AS varchar(max))
                           ELSE ''
                      END
    FROM dbo.Nodes AS n
    INNER JOIN AllNodes AS an 
    ON an.NodeID = n.ParentNodeID
)
SELECT an.NodeID, an.IsDisabled, an.NodeName,
       an.ParentNodeID, an.NodeLevel, an.NodePath,
       dbo.GetParentNode(an.NodePath) AS TrueParentNodeID
FROM AllNodes AS an
WHERE an.IsDisabled = 0;

DROP TABLE dbo.Nodes;
GO
```

Just execute the whole thing and see if it looks right. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing a working example. I took what you had and modified it to work with the hierarchyid data type (which makes doing what you're trying to do pretty easy. First, the modified setup code:

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        anchor.Id AS ItemId, 
        skipNode,
        anchor.ParentId AS ItemParentId, 
        1 AS Lvl, 
        anchor.[Name],
        CAST(concat('/', id, '/') AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS NodePath
    FROM
        #Node anchor 
    WHERE 
        anchor.[Id] = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        nextDepth.Id AS ItemId, 
        nextDepth.skipNode, 
        nextDepth.ParentId AS ItemParentId, 
        Lvl+1 AS Lvl, 
        nextDepth.[Name],
        CAST(concat(rec.NodePath, nextDepth.[id], '/') AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS NodePath
    FROM 
        #Node nextDepth
    INNER JOIN 
        RCTE rec ON nextDepth.ParentId = rec.ItemId
)
SELECT ItemId, skipNode , ItemParentId, [Name], cast(NodePath as [hierarchyid]) as NodePath
into dbo.rcte
FROM RCTE AS hierarchy
GO
```

The only two modifications were the formatting of NodePath (which is now a slash-separated list of IDs instead of Names) and dumping the results to a table now (instead of a raw result set). Now, a stored procedure that takes in an ItemID and removes it from the table (updating anything it depended on accordingly).

```
create or alter procedure RemoveItem (
    @ItemID int
)
AS
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @NewParent hierarchyid = (
        select parent.NodePath
        from dbo.rcte as child
        join dbo.rcte as parent
            on child.ItemParentId = parent.ItemId
        where child.ItemId = @ItemID
    ), @OldParent hierarchyid = (
        select Child.NodePath
        from dbo.rcte as child
        where child.ItemId = @ItemID
    ), @NewParentItemID int = (
        select Child.ItemParentId
        from dbo.rcte as child
        where child.ItemId = @ItemID
    );

    update r
    set NodePath = NodePath.GetReparentedValue(@OldParent, @NewParent),
        ItemParentId = case 
            when ItemParentId = @ItemID 
            then @NewParentItemID 
            else ItemParentId
        end
    from dbo.rcte as r
    where NodePath.IsDescendantOf(@OldParent) = 1
        and r.ItemId <> @ItemID;

    delete dbo.rcte
    where ItemId = @ItemID;
end
go
```

With that done, I can now just call the sproc with the node I want to remove:

```
exec dbo.RemoveItem @ItemID = 2;

select *, NodePath.ToString()
from dbo.rcte;
```

Note, if I were writing that sproc for real, I'd have more in there (i.e. check if the thing I'm trying to delete actually exists, check if the *parent* exists, etc), but the bones of the solution are there.